# How to inject a Singleton into non-Singleton users with Dagger 2?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I have a simple Dagger setup, where some things are Singleton and some are not:

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = [TaskComponent::class])
interface SingletonComponent {
  fun single(): MySingleton
}

@Component
interface TaskComponent {
  fun task(): MyTask
}

@Singleton class MySingleton @Inject constructor() {}

class MyTask @Inject constructor(val single: MySingleton) {}
```

Now, I want to create multiple `MyTask` instances that use the single `MySingleton` instances:

```
val taskComponent = DaggerTaskComponent.create()
taskComponent.task().longRunningProcess()
taskComponent.task().longRunningProcess()
```

The problem is, Dagger won't inject my singleton into anything else:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] MyTask cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Or, if I add a random scope annotation to `TaskComponent`:

> error: This @Singleton component cannot depend on scoped components

I've gone through several combinations of singleton and not-singleton, but nothing seems to work. How do I get Dagger to allow me to use my singletons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a provision function with which you will provide whatever it is listed in dependency of your component `@Component(dependencies = [TaskComponent::class])`. Why do you even need the `TaskComponent`?

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = [TaskComponent::class])
interface SingletonComponent {
  fun single(): MySingleton
  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder : {
     fun taskComponent(taskComponent : TaskComponent) : Builder
     fun build(): SingletonComponent
   }
}
```

then just do

```
DaggerSingletonComponent.taskComponent(DaggerTaskComponent.create()).build()
```

Scoped components can depend on unscoped components, that's fine.

Comment: But this way, I'm just doing manual injection. I expect Dagger to know the `Singleton` goes into the `Task`, that shouldn't be my problem when creating a `Task`. That's the whole point of using a DI framework.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked why do you need TaskComponent.

Comment: To create `Task`s? I feel like I'm missing the point of the question...

Comment: You don't need a component to create `Task`, `MyTask` already has `@Inject` on the  constructor, dagger creates factory for that class.  You may need component dependencies if you want to hierarchically order the components.

Comment: There's a `Task_Factory`, but that still requires me to pass in a `Singleton`. I want Dagger to give me new `Task`s without making *me* provide dependencies.

Comment: As @NikolaDespotoski said, you don't need multiple components. You can have just `SingletonComponent` with one function: `task(): MyTask`.